# static counter in c++

Tags: c++, class, static, counter

I'm trying to create a `Data` class whose objects each hold a unique ID.

I want the 1st object's ID to be 1, the 2nd to be 2, etc. I must use a `static int`, but *all* the objects have the same ID, not 1, 2, 3...

This is the `Data` class:

```
class Data
{
private:
   static int ID;
public:
   Data(){
   ID++;
   }
};
```

How can I do it so the first one ID would be 1, the second would be 2, etc..?

Comment: Make sure that you take care of multithreading, as the variable is `static`.

Comment: Generally people use `long` for this rather than `int`.

Comment: @shan: Which people? It can be whatever he wants.

Comment: @0A0D `long` is wider than `int`. If we don't know how many objects we want, better to use `long`.

Comment: @shan: It will rollover back to negative (or zero if it is unsigned). `long` will rollover eventually too. Unsigned int goes to 65535. It all depends on the application.

Comment: @shan: It depends on the architecture and compiler. In many architectures `long` is exactly the same size as `int`. On the other hand, it *should* really be `unsigned` (of whatever length). @0A0D: `unsigned int` goes to 65535?? what architecture are you on that still has 16bit `int`?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "*... but all the objects have the same ID, not 1, 2, 3..*"

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Oops, meant unsigned short.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: The standard answer to 'what architecture are you on that still has 16bit int?' - an embedded system of some kind. They do exist.

Answer (score 23):

This:

```
class Data
{
private:
   static int ID;
   const int currentID;
public:
   Data() : currentID(ID++){
   }
};
```

Besides a static counter, you also need an instance-bound member.

Comment: The member id should be a `const` field. Once the object is created it probably makes little to no sense to change it. It will also automatically inhibit `operator=` from overwriting the id of the object, even though the user is left with the responsibility of providing a copy constructor that does not reuse the source object's id.

Comment: I hit some error using `const` perhaps due to my user-declared copy constructor. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37517125/5272567). Removing `const` "fixed" this, of course that means the variable isn't `const`.

Comment: What value is `ID` initialized to here, and how?

Comment: @dekuShrub the initialization is left out, there's an example in Brady's answer.

Comment: I thought it might be the case, but wasn't sure since my linter didn't complain when I tried without it, thanks! ^^

Answer (score 16):

If the ID is static, then it will have the same value for all class instances.

If you want each instance to have sequential id values, then you could combine the static attribute with a class variable, like this:

```
class Data
{
private:
   static int ID;
   int thisId;
public:
   Data(){
   thisId = ++ID;
   }
};

int Data::ID = 0;
```

If the application will be multi threaded, then you'll have to synchronize it with something like a pthread mutex.

Comment: thanks, thought about this solution but I was wondering if there is another way to do it, only with the static int, since I was requested to do it using static int only. thanks! :)

Comment: @Jjang, you could do it with just one static int if you just print the value in the constructor, but if you need to ***store*** the unique sequential value, then you'll need more than just the static int.

Comment: @Jjang: You cannot have *unique* id's per object with a single *shared* id (`static`), that makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 4):

Initialization of static variable within a function is allowed so a solution can be something like this

```
 class Data
 {
    private:
    static int ID ()
    {
       static int ID = 0;
       return ID ++;
    }
    int myId;

    public:
    Data(): myId (ID ())
    {      
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of `Data` needs its own non-static member variable that stores its ID. A `static` variable can be used to store the last used ID which would be incremented in the constructor of `Data`.

Instead of a `static` counter, which is not thread-safe, consider using [boost's uuid](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html):

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>

using boost::lexical_cast;
using boost::uuids::uuid;
using boost::uuids::random_generator;

std::string id_ = lexical_cast<std::string>((random_generator())());
```

Answer (score 0):

where is the instance(non static) id here? you need to declare a new instance ID field like this

```
int m_ID;
```

then in your constructor do

```
Data(){m_ID = ::InterlockedIncrement(&ID);}
```

in an [interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683614%28VS.85%29.aspx#) or other thread-safe way

Comment: Nice idea, but how portable is that?

Comment: Not portable at all of course ;-) I was just giving an example.