# Why my own type can not be declared but I used Q_DECLARE_METATYPE?

Tags: c++, qt, qmetatype

I have a problem with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE:

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2280   'MyNamespace::MyClass::MyClass(const MyNamespace::MyClass&)': attempting to reference a deleted function    BksMtRisk   C:\qt2\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qmetatype.h    825**

What is wrong?

```
namespace MyNamespace {
class MyClass : public AbstractMyClass
{
 
}
}
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyNamespace::MyClass)
```

Comment: I don't know but for my situation need function `MyClass (const MyClass & other)` , why I need create this function???

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Type):

> This macro makes the type Type known to QMetaType as long as it provides a public default constructor, a public copy constructor and a public destructor. It is needed to use the type Type as a custom type in QVariant.

So my guess is that your base class is missing one of the required **Public Constructors**

For more information read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31266254

Comment: If I writing: `MyClass(const MyClass& other) = default;` I get all the same error

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example